# Is there any way to handle java Script based Pop up in selenium (Java) without using alert.dismiss method?

Tags: java, selenium, testing, automation, automated-tests

[Image attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wr8nK.png) I have used Alert.dismiss(); but it is not working. I want to click on cancel button. Is there any other way to handle. I have tried considering this pop up as window.

Please find image in attachment.

Comment: Update the question with the text based HTML and your code trials.

Answer (score 0):

Try to click on the cancel button:

```
WebElement cancelBtn = driver.findElementByXpath("//button[contains(text(),'cancel')]");
cancelBtn.click();
```

If this doesn't work, see if the pop-up is inside an Iframe. If so switch to the Iframe and then look for the cancel button.

```
driver.switchToIframe(0);
// or
driver.switchToIfrmae("IDOfTheIframe");
```

Comment: Questions: 1) How did you conclude it's the _innerText_ as _**cancel**_ but not the _title_? 2) How did you conclude the frame index is `0`? 3) How did you conclude the frame have a id/name as `IDOfTheIframe`?

Comment: @undetectedSelenium 1) I did Not, I just gave an example. Most odds the element is a button. 2) Again, just an example of how to switch Iframe by index. 3) Just an example, the tester will have to write the correct ID of the Iframe of course